# Mongodb fails with exit code 14 on startup

Tags: mongodb

I`m trying to start up mongo and I keep getting this message when I check the status.

```
mongod.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2016-12-27 15:14:43 CST; 56s ago
Process: 29940 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod $OPTIONS run (code=exited, status=14)
Process: 29928 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/percona-server-mongodb-helper.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 29940 (code=exited, status=14)

Dec 27 15:14:43 debian systemd[1]: Started High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database.
Dec 27 15:14:43 debian mongod[29940]: 2016-12-27T15:14:43.177-0600 I STORAGE  Compression: snappy
Dec 27 15:14:43 debian mongod[29940]: 2016-12-27T15:14:43.177-0600 I STORAGE  MaxWriteMBPerSec: 1024
Dec 27 15:14:43 debian mongod[29940]: 2016-12-27T15:14:43.177-0600 I STORAGE  Crash safe counters: 0
Dec 27 15:14:43 debian systemd[1]: mongod.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=14/n/a
Dec 27 15:14:43 debian systemd[1]: Unit mongod.service entered failed state.
```

Any ideas on what the issue potentially is? I have tried all the acepted answers along the subject to fix it like deleting the lock file, restarting, and redownloading but Have gotten the same issue. I am using the preconda mongo build

Comment: What is your config file and what is your start command?

Comment: I left all the defaults in config besides changing the engine to rocks from mmap. could you explain what you mean by start command?

Comment: are you using `sudo service mongod start` or `restart` ?

Comment: I tried both but got the same error

Comment: you should add the command you used, not just the error output. can't debug one without the other.